# Convert IMP to a func in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c-runtime

I'm trying to do this in my code:

```
typealias voidIMP = (NSObject, Selector, String) -> ()

let string = NSMutableString()
var selector = Selector("setString:")

var setStringMethod: IMP = string.methodForSelector("setString:")
let callBack =  Unmanaged.fromOpaque(setStringMethod).takeUnretainedValue() as AnyObject as! voidIMP

for _ in 0..<1000 {
   callBack(string, selector, "stuff")
}
```

But the app crashed in line 5 with `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` error.

How do I use `IMP` in Swift? I tried to convert `IMP(setStringMethod)` to a `func`, but didn't work. The Objective-C version works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are **two ways** to achieve this. First one, rather unsafe, makes use of bit casting and is based on your example:

```
typealias setStringIMP = @convention(c) (NSObject, Selector, String) -> Void

let string = NSMutableString()
let selector = Selector("setString:")

let callback = unsafeBitCast(string.methodForSelector(selector), setStringIMP.self)

callback(string, selector, "stuff")
```

Please note `@convention(c)` in `typealias` – this tells the compiler that you're typealiasing a C function.

---

If you'd like just to use a method as a callback, though, since **methods are first-class functions**, you can do the following:

```
let string = NSMutableString()
let callback = string.setString

callback("stuff")
```

This is much safer than using unsafe bit casting.